# Scroll container pushing parallel div to the right instead of creating a horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make my `scroll__container` scroll on the x axis. However, whenever I add a new div to the container, it pushes the div I have on the right, further to the right and doesn't create a scrollbar.

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
<div className="themesContainer">
      <div className="themes__skinContainer">
        <div className="themes__tag">
          <h6>Skins</h6>
        </div>
        <div className="skins__container">
          <h6>Primary Colors</h6>
          <div className="scroll__container">
            <div onClick={setBlackTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Black</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setBlueTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Blue</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setRedTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Red</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setYellowTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Yellow</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setGreenTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Green</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setPurpleTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Purple</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setOrangeTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Orange</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setPinkTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Pink</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my css:

```js
.themesContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px 150px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.themes__skinContainer {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: none;
}

.themes__tag {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.themes__tag > h6 {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.scroll__container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.skin__option {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, I see a scrollbar:

[image]

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-babbage-bdypr)

However, on mobile devices the scrollbar is only visible *while scrolling*. This is normal behaviour. The same goes for viewing a page while Chrome devtools option **Toggle device toolbar** is enabled:

[image]

If you want to make scrollbars permanently visible on mobile, you will need to use vendor prefixes or implement a custom toolbar component. I recommend against doing so, because as I mentioned this is normal behaviour so there may not be any UX issues here.